# Change several events on onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, i18next

I have two buttons for changing language created by the .map function. I also use i18next to change languages.

When clicked on a button corresponding to a certain language, I want not only the language of a page to change, but to change the styling of a button (e.g. make background white).

I have managed to do the following with useState, however, it changes the ctyling of two buttons simultaneously.

Code:

```
const languages = [
  {
    code: 'en',
    name: 'English',
    country_code: 'gb',
    emoji: ''
  },

  {
    code: 'uk',
    name: 'Українська',
    country_code: 'ua',
    emoji: ''
  }
]



const Langbar = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsActive(current => !current);
  };
  return (
    <div className='container langbar_container'>
      <h3>{t('language')}</h3>
    {languages.map(({code, emoji}) => (
            <button 
            onClick={() => {i18next.changeLanguage(code); handleClick}}
            className="btn btn-secondary langbar_btn"
            style={{
              background: isActive ? 'white' : ''}
            }>
              <span>{emoji}</span>
            </button>
    ))}
</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have only one isActive value that you're having the buttons share, so changing that value changes it for both. You're going to need to track them either as separate state values or by tracking *which* button is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```html
const Langbar = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [isLangCode, setLangCode] = useState("");

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLanCode(current => !current);
  };
  return (
    <div className='container langbar_container'>
      <h3>{t('language')}</h3>
    {languages.map(({code, emoji}) => (
            <button 
            onClick={() => {i18next.changeLanguage(code); handleClick}}
            className="btn btn-secondary langbar_btn"
            style={{
              background: isLangCode == code ? 'white' : ''}
            }>
              <span>{emoji}</span>
            </button>
    ))}
</div>
  )
}
```